# Variation of phase across the wavefront

Tags: electromagnetism, diffraction, space

I have been going through the theory of diffraction of radio waves when passing through the ionosphere, when I came across the following statement:

> the amplitude of the wave when it emerges from the ionosphere is sensibly constant over the wavefront, but the phase varies across the wavefront!

in the introduction of A. Hewish, The diffraction of radio waves in passing through a phase-changing ionosphere, [*Proc. R. Soc. Lond. A* **209**, 81 (1951)](https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.1951.0189).

I am confused by "*the phase varies across the wavefront*" since as per my current understanding, a wavefront is the locus of all points having the same phase in an electromagnetic wave! Then how come phase vary over the wavefront?

Comment: You're right to be confused. Where did you find this?

Comment: Could he mean that there are small, but somehow significant, fluctuations of phase on a distance scale much smaller than the wavelength?

Comment: The ionosphere acts as a high pass filter and it's not a perfect, square filter, so my guess is there may be some phase and gain corrections necessary near the cutoff to reproduce the incident EM radiation properties.